# Joda-time Period doesn't seem to calculate days correctly

Tags: java, jodatime, period

I am seeing some strange behavior around the Joda-time `Period` class -- specifically the days processing.  In the following example code, I am specifying a period of 26 hours as milliseconds.

```
// 26 hour duration
long durationMillis = 26 * 3600 * 1000;
Period period = new Period(durationMillis, PeriodType.dayTime());
// this fails because days == 0
assertEquals(1, period.getDays());
// this would fail because hours == 26
assertEquals(2, period.getHours());
```

I was expecting that `Period` would see that 26 hours is 1 day and 2 hours but it doesn't seem to be recognizing that a day == 24 hours.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that Joda-time is wicked smaaaaart.  I guess that it can't know the number of hours in a day because of daylight savings time and other timezone issues.  There might be 23 or 25 hours in any particular day for example.

To force it to a 24 hours/day, you need to specific a `Chronology` that is consistent about hours per day.

```
long durationMillis = 26 * 3600 * 1000;
Period period = new Period(durationMillis, PeriodType.dayTime(),
    ISOChronology.getInstanceUTC());
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is needed to have 1 day == 24 hours
// this works!
assertEquals(1, period.getDays());
// this works!
assertEquals(2, period.getHours());
```